# Why doesn't Visual Studio and nuget.exe share the same libraries?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

[Visual Studio interfaces with NuGet via a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28176425/2687324), but the command line tool is solely an exe (nuget.exe).

Is there a reason they don't share a common library? It seems like this introduces the risk of allowing for code divergence between the dll and exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio and NuGet.exe share a common library called NuGet.Core.dll. Things have changed a bit with NuGet 3.0 but they still share dlls.

The NuGet.exe has the NuGet.Core.dll merged into it instead of having a separate file.